# Sort members within a region via ReSharper Code Cleanup

Tags: c#, resharper, region

Using ReSharper Code Cleanup, is there a way to apply the `sort by`/`then by` settings for a member type within a region? In my file layout settings, I have `Fields` configured to `Sort By: Readonly`, `Then By: Access`. This works great for fields not inside a region.

But, if members are already inside a region (and should stay in the region), how can I configure ReSharper to Code Cleanup within the region? It does not seem to re-order the members in the region using the Default Layout.

Before:

```
#region

public string var3;
private string var4;
public readonly string var1;
private readonly string var2;
public string var5;

#endregion
```

Desired Result:

```
#region

public readonly string var1;
private readonly string var2;
public string var3;
public string var5;
private string var4;

#endregion
```

Comment: Is "Fields" entry in the File Layout embraced with a region with the same name as fields in the code? ReSharper omits existed regions if the same ones are not specified in the File Layout.

Comment: Hmm, no. This is a legacy codebase with varying regions often by logical grouping (not type grouping). So, a region might be a domain-specific name like "members for account access". So, I couldn't list all of those in the file layout options. Ideally, these need to be broken into classes, but as a step in that direction, it'd be nice to organize within regions.

Comment: As I mentioned before, ReSharper does not touch any code in unknown regions. And I don't think removing these regions is an option in such case. AFAIK then there is no way to sort these fields (or any other entities in custom regions), it is a by-design behavior.